# How to configure mod_rewrite with an Alias in Apache 2.4?

Tags: networking, apache-httpd, mod-rewrite

How do I use apache mod_rewrite with an Alias ?
I have a test directory that contains the files:
correct.html  index.html  test_httpd.conf  wrong.html
I would like an example rule using an alias that directs any requests to wrong.html be redirected to correct.html.
And another example rule that directs any requests for any files in the directory test to point to correct.html
Here is what I have tried in my test_httpd.conf:

```
#DocumentRoot /var/www/localhost/htdocs/test
Alias /test /var/www/localhost/htdocs/test/
#<Directory /var/www/localhost/htdocs/test>
#<Directory /test>
<Directory test>
  RewriteEngine On
  #RewriteRule ^*$ rewriteme.html [R]
  RewriteRule ^wrong.html$ correct.html [R]
</Directory>
```

I am on apache 2.4.6-r2 on Gentoo.

Comment: Try to add a `RewriteBase /test/` within your `Directory` block. PS: you should have `<Directory /var/www/localhost/htdocs/test/>`, not `<Directory test>`.

Comment: That gives me a:Not Found

The requested URL /var/www/localhost/htdocs/test/correct.html was not found on this server.

Comment: `#DocumentRoot /var/www/localhost/htdocs/test
Alias /test /var/www/localhost/htdocs/test/
<Directory /var/www/localhost/htdocs/test/>
#<Directory /test>
#<Directory test>
  RewriteBase /test/
  RewriteEngine On
  #RewriteRule ^*$ rewriteme.html [R]
  RewriteRule ^wrong.html$ correct.html [R]
</Directory>`

Comment: Nevermind I had to clear the browser cache. Yes it works! Thanks. It only works with the RewriteBase /test and I think the trailing / was not necessary.

Comment: Essentially mod_rewrite can not use an alias?

Comment: No: when a part of the HTTP path is "virtual" (Alias, VirtualDocumentRoot, UserDir, ...), mod_rewrite is "lost", a RewriteBase is required.